# Links do not show in hamburger menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap for the first time and no matter what I do, I do not get the hamburger menu right. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navnavnav">
    &#9776;
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="http://image.jpg" width="60" height="52" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navnavnav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size: 1.5em">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problem exactly are you facing? This just works fine--
Just add your cdns in the below mentioned manner

**working example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navnavnav">
    &#9776;
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="http://image.jpg" width="60" height="52" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navnavnav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size: 1.5em">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Was a problem with Codepen. Added the cdns manually and it works now!

Comment: if it has helped please accept the answer..Welcome to SO..in SO if a answer helps we upvote it and if the answer solves your problem we accept it ..that's how SO works and it prevents spam answers.